# Xamp object not found

Tags: php, xampp

Since I've changed my secondary drive, xamp doesn't work anymore.
Everything in c:\ is the same as before.
I've got my php code in htdocs folder (same as httpd.conf) but when I type in firefox `http://localhost/xamp/Mywebsite/index.php` it says object not found.

EDIT. Correct path is `http://localhost/Mywebsite/index.php`

Comment: It is `xampp`, not `xamp` . You may have a typo

Comment: The correct URL (on a default installation) should be: `http://localhost/Mywebsite/index.php`